# Taylor series the approximation environment

Tags: calculus

Suppose I want to calculate an approximation of root 10,what's my a?
According to what a is determined?[image]

Comment: What is $f(x)$?

Comment: root 10 or 10^1/2

Comment: I beg your pardon, but $f(x)$is a function.

Comment: Sorry, I got confused,root 10 That's the calculation at the end,The function is simple f(x)= root x

Answer (score 1):

**hint**

To make the computation pratical, in general, we take $ a=0 $, and we choose un function $ f $ for which we have the expression of the successive derivatives.

In your case, as you want to aproach the value of $ \sqrt{10} $, you will take

$$f(x)=\sqrt{1+x} =(1+x)^\frac 12$$

and use the well known expansion, for $ |x|<1$,

$$(1+x)^b=1+bx+...\frac{b(b-1)...+(b-n+1)}{n!}x^n+...$$
thus

$$\sqrt{1+9}=3\sqrt{1+\frac 19}=$$
$$=3(1+\frac 12\frac19-\frac 18(\frac 19)^2+...)$$

Comment: It converges only for $|x|<1$.

Comment: If I understood correctly we simply choose the closest number that has a Integer  root?

Comment: @complex_stock The Taylor Series expansion for ${\sqrt{1+x}}$ is what he wrote above; the problem is, it only converges for ${|x|<1}$. So he rewrote ${\sqrt{10}}$ as ${3\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{9}}}$, since ${\left|\frac{1}{9}\right|<1}$ - he can now use the Taylor Series and approximate ${\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{9}}}$ and just multiply it by ${3}$ to get an approximate answer for ${\sqrt{10}}$

Comment: In my opinion, if it's only for $\sqrt{10}$, the algorithm taught in medschool (a layout like hand-made division)  does the job as well.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand the subject well enough,can you recommend me an article or video on the topic that explains taylor series In a simple way even to fools like me?

Comment: @Bernard Ah I didn't realise that pre-edit the answer used the series ${\sqrt{1+x}}$ with ${x=9}$ - the factoring was only added after your comment, my bad (I only just looked at the pre-edit). And yeah that's true, that Algorithm would be fine. I think the question OP was answering though probably required the use of Taylor Series

Comment: @complex_stock 3b1b did an amazing video on providing an intuitive approach to Taylor Series: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3d6DsjIBzJ4 . With Taylor Series, we are trying to represent a function as an infinite polynomial. This is done by matching the value of the function and all it's derivatives at a point to the polynomial (the function must be infinitely differentiable). To approximate functions, you can take a finite number of the terms in this polynomial. In this case - using the series for ${\sqrt{1+x}}$ allows you to approximate the square root of numbers between ${0}$ and ${2}$

Comment: @complex_stock Since the Taylor Series for ${\sqrt{1+x}}$ only converges when ${-1 < x < 1}$, he turned ${\sqrt{10}}$ into ${3\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{9}}}$ (they are the same thing), and **then** used the series (taking finitely many terms gave him the approximation)